Understanding a weird Cardano transaction with repeated addresses
Can anyone explain this transaction?
https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/4911eeec04808b593a34f527bc54ca9c6bf511d6e1ce2a8d2f813f7faaaaa9c9?tab=summary
It features one input and, as outputs, includes the contract (script address) alongside the same address repeated five times, plus some reward withdrawals.
I created the contract (script) and its enterprise address to lock (or 'burn') tokens. I'm puzzled about how and why this transaction occurred.
You can observe dozens of standard transactions on the same script here:
https://cardanoscan.io/address/71ddeef9f90c80761867d2371cbb8003b4d5559ba795640e7042ca01ed?tab=transactions
This is the first time I've encountered such an odd transaction.

What's strange about it? The fact that it creates multiple UTxOs in the sender's wallet is an optimization for the parallelism of the future transactions.
